# vector elements do not appear to be stored contigously

Tags: c++, vector

Why does the last expected output differ from the actual output in the following code?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<istream>
#include<sstream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
        vector<int> v;
        for(int ii = 0; ii < 4; ii++){
            v.push_back(0);
        }

        vector<vector<int>> twoDv;

        for(int ii = 0; ii < 5; ii++){
            twoDv.push_back(v);
        }

        cout<<"Expected Output : " << &twoDv[0][0] <<'\t'<< (&twoDv[0][0] + 3) <<'\t'<< (&twoDv[0][3] + 1)<<'\n';
        cout<<"Actual Output   : " << &twoDv[0][0] <<'\t'<< &twoDv[0][3] <<'\t'<< &twoDv[1][0] << '\n';
}
```

Comment: So what is the expected/actual output? My guess is that you wanted to do something else than adding `v` five times into `twoDv`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard doesn't say that `&twoDv[1][0]` is equal to `&twoDv[0][3] + 1`. It says that `&twoDv[1]` is equal to `&twoDv[0] + 1`, and that `&twoDv[0][1]` is equal to `&twoDv[0][0] + 1`.

Suppose for a moment that `&twoDv[1][0]` *were* equal to `&twoDv[0][3] + 1`, and then you did `twoDv[0].resize(5);`. Suddenly we have a conflict, `&twoDv[0][3] + 1` can't be the address of `&twoDv[1][0]` and *also* the address of `&twoDv[0][4]`. So the resize operation on `twoDv[0]` would have to invalidate iterators and references to the elements of another vector `twoDv[1]`. This would be very undesirable behavior.

Answer (score 5):

`vector< vector< int > >` is not a two-dimensional array like `int[5][5]`. It's an array of pointers to arrays. <sub><sup>(To be more precise, it contains a sequence of `std::vector` objects containing pointers to integers.)</sup></sub> Only the "rows" are contiguous. Different rows are not contiguous with each other because they may be stored in different malloc'ed blocks of memory.

Answer (score 5):

A `vector` does store its elements in continuous memory. But the elements of `vector<vector<int>> twoDv;` are vectors, not ints, and the ints are stored in continuous memory internally, **per vector**.

[image]

Think of an array of pointers:

```
int* x[10];
```

The `10` pointers are stored in continuous memory, but *what they point to* doesn't have to be in continuous memory.